# Remove items from list if they are already in txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to run this code but im having a problem, it's not working as i need.
What i need is to check if a code from the items list is already saved in the file.txt if it's already there i need to delete that item from the list.
And then save the items list as string in a new file.txt

```
items = [['e5860', '2020-06-10'], ['e6056', '2020-06-10'], ['e6008', '2020-06-10'], ['100080020', '2020-06-10'], ['e6463', '2020-06-10'], ['KW13012', '2020-06-10'], ['e3589', '2020-06-10']]

for i, item in enumerate(items):
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        if item[0] in f.read():
            items.pop(items.index(item))

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(items))

print(items)
```

When i first run this code file.txt will be empty so the output should be:

```
[['e5860', '2020-06-10'], ['e6056', '2020-06-10'], ['e6008', '2020-06-10'], ['100080020', '2020-06-10'], ['e6463', '2020-06-10'], ['KW13012', '2020-06-10'], ['e3589', '2020-06-10']]
```

Then if i run the same code again the output should be a empty items list (because they are all saved in the file before and deleted from the list).
But when i run this the first output is correct, i get the list from items, if i run it again then im getting this as output:

```
[['e6056', '2020-06-10'], ['100080020', '2020-06-10'], ['KW13012', '2020-06-10']]
```

Why this codes wasn't deleted from the list?

---

I figured out that the items deleted from the list are the even numbers of the list. But i can't understand why :/

Comment: It a pretty bad idea to read the whole file for every item in the list. It would be better to read the file *once*, process it into something like a set and *then* iterate the list. It would be easier to give specific advice if you showed a bit of the file contents.

Comment: The file at the first run it's empty. I need it to store the data so i can access it when i open my .py file again. It's like a temporary database, without using database. Also the file will be erased with the second run of the script. 
First run -> Save 
Second run -> Use it like db then erase

Comment: @MarkMeyer how can I read the file once and process into a set? Im new to python trying to learn

Comment: It's unclear what's going on. It sounds like if the file is empty at first run, then it won't delete anything from the list. Then you are going to write your items to that file (which will be all the items). Then on the second run *all* the items will be in the file, so all the items will be deleted. Then you write an empty file? Clearly we're missing something.

Comment: That's what im trying to achieve. In the actually script the value of the list will change of course. But for this example im using the same just to be able to print an empty list, so i know the script is working fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save your list as a list, you can use the json module to serialize it. This will let you load and save the list easily.

Then you can load the file and process a data structure that will let you test easily for inclusion. A set is the obvious choice. Once you have that you can filter your list based on whether items are in this set and then dump the list back to the file.

This assumes a file already exists (even if it's empty):

```
items = [['e5860', '2020-06-10'], ['e6056', '2020-06-10'], ['e6008', '2020-06-10'], ['100080020', '2020-06-10'], ['e6463', '2020-06-10'], ['KW13012', '2020-06-10'], ['e3589', '2020-06-10']]


with open(filePath, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    if data:
        file_items = json.loads(data)

        # create a set of just the first items in the sub lists:
        seen = set(item[0] for item in file_items)

    else: # empty file, make an empty set
        seen = set()

filtered = [item for item in items if item[0] not in seen]

print(filtered)


with open(filePath, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(filtered,f)
```

This will alternate between an empty file and a file that contains json of all your `items`

Comment: This is working fine. Also I understand now why mine wasn't working. While i was deleting the items from the list the total number of the list was decreasing by 1, but the for statment was set to te initial total items and the index was never changing.